# Compressing multiple files into a single file with last weeks date in the name using batch file

Tags: date, batch-file, 7zip

Can anyone please help.
I am trying set a scheduled task that runs daily to compress log files older than 7 days into a single zip file but with the date of the log file as the zip name, not the current date.

The best I have managed to get so far is to use the current date in the file name... I want the date 7 days ago as the file name.

My script currently reads:

```
SET SourceDir=D:\test\Logs
SET TmpDir=D:\test\Temp
SET DestinationDir=D:\test\Dest

ROBOCOPY "%SourceDir%" "%TmpDir%" *.log /MOV /MINAGE:7 
FOR %%A IN (%TmpDir%\*.*) DO "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "%DestinationDir%\Logs-%date:~-4%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-10,2%.zip" "%%A" 
RMDIR /S /Q "%TmpDir%"
```

Can anyone please help me so that the date of the zip file is not the date the file is created but 7 days ago?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.  Someone from another site gave me a powershell command for getting the current date and then taking any number of days off.

The powershell command was:

```
for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`PowerShell $date ^= Get-Date^; $date ^= $date.AddDays^(-7^)^; $date.ToString^('yyyy-MM-dd'^)`) do echo Logs-%%i.zip
```

Its the (-7) bit that actually dictates how many days you want to go back.  I have also been told that you can use this command for going forward in time by using a possative number as apposed to a negative one.

I then had to tweak it a little to get its output as a variable in order to add into my command.

My final script is:

```
SET SourceDir=D:\test\Logs
SET TmpDir=D:\test\Temp
SET DestinationDir=D:\test\Dest
for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`PowerShell $date ^= Get-Date^; $date ^= $date.AddDays^(-7^)^; $date.ToString^('yyyy-MM-dd'^)`) do set LOGDATE=%%i

ROBOCOPY "%SourceDir%" "%TmpDir%" *.log /MOV /MINAGE:7 
FOR %%A IN (%TmpDir%\*.*) DO "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "%DestinationDir%\Logs-%LOGDATE%.zip" "%%A" 
RMDIR /S /Q "%TmpDir%"
```